# How to pass user input to Apple Script then execute?

Tags: applescript, automator

How do I configure Automator to ask for a text input (example: enter website url) and pass the answer to an AppleScript that executes this command:

```
video-dl (user input)
```

So, this would be executed in the terminal:

```
video-dl http://www.example.com/video.mpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use AppleScript here, you can pass data from Automator directly into a shell script.

[image]

Depending on where you've stored the script, you may have to include the full path to the script in the action (`/path/to/video-dl "$@"`).

Comment: Any idea how you can show a window that shows progress? You rock!

Comment: Not really, might be tricky from Automator. Please ask a new question for this if necessary.